# Curl POST Form Request with Hidden Input Values

Tags: curl, http-post

I'm trying to use curl to automate requesting occupation codes from the Australian Bureau of Statistics web page. I'm getting a "Search Index does not exist" error when I do a POST request with Curl. I think the problem is that there are two inputs that I'm not entering, and so it is failing. I would appreciate any assistance on this:

Curl request:

```
curl --data "searchcontent=&helpdocid=[docid]&searchtext=121315&submit=Go" http://www.ausstats.abs.gov.au/ausstats/searchclass.nsf/(Searchattmnt)?openagent
```

The relevant code from the ABS site is this:

```
<!-- Start Search Content -->
<div id="titlemain"> Search Results</div><div id="middle"></div>
<form name="attmnt" method="post" action="http://www.ausstats.abs.gov.au/ausstats/searchclass.NSF/(Searchattmnt)?openagent"> 
<input type="hidden" name="searchcontent" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="helpdocid" value="[docid]">
<div id="content">
<h3>New Search :</h3>
<input type="text" name="searchtext" size =60 MAXLENGTH="255" value="">   
<INPUT VALUE="Go" TYPE="submit">
</form>
</div>
<!-- End Search Content -->
```

Let me know if anything else would help. I'm staring down the barrel of some serious data entry if I can't get this to work.

EDIT: Just fixed up the typo in the curl request to avoid confusion.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the POST from the web page using a tool like Wireshark?  That may be more accurate than trying to decipher the HTML.

Comment: Might be a typo here, but &sumbit should be &submit (if it's even needed). Also, those hidden elements value may actually be set with javascript based on user action.

Comment: @Justin Morgan - No I haven't I'll try that.

@Bill N - Yeah that would've been a typo copying it across. If that is the case, can I still use curl to submit this post, or will it prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used @Justin Morgan's suggestion and ran wireshark while I performed the request. This gave me the values that I required. In the end this was the curl request I used that worked:

```
curl \
-d "searchcontent=1220.0Data%2BCubes-SuperTable25.06.091" \
-d "helpdocid=17441354B1295875CA2571E6000AE9A0" \
-d "searchtext=121318" \
http://www.ausstats.abs.gov.au/ausstats/searchclass.NSF/(Searchattmnt)?openagent
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that curl's `--data` parameter sends the text exactly as you provide it, but you are not url-encoding reserved characters (specifically, the `[` and `]` characters), so the server will not be able to match up the value of the `helpdocid` field correctly.

On a side note, don't include the "submit=Go" field in your posted data.  Only fields with both names and values get submitted.

Try this:

```
curl --data "searchcontent=&helpdocid=%5Bdocid%5D&searchtext=121315" http://www.ausstats.abs.gov.au/ausstats/searchclass.nsf/(Searchattmnt)?openagent
```

Comment: I used @Justin Morgan's suggestion and ran wireshark while I performed the request. This gave me the values that I required. In the end this was the curl request I used that worked:

`curl --data "searchcontent=1220.0Data%2BCubes-SuperTable25.06.091&helpdocid=17441354B1295875CA2571E6000AE9A0&searchtext=121318" http://www.ausstats.abs.gov.au/ausstats/searchclass.NSF/(Searchattmnt)?openagent`

Answer (score 0):

The Mozilla plug-in `livehttpheader` shows the string of urlencoded text used to post to the server.